# error when i try to install ez-publish on ubuntu apache2

Tags: php, apache, symfony, ubuntu, ezpublish

I'm trying to install ez-publish 5.12 on my UBUNTU server 14.04 with PHP Version 5.6.17-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 , so when i try php composer.phar install i get this error :

```
[RuntimeException]                                                              
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:       

[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException]          
Invalid type for path "framework.secret". Expected scalar, but got object.                                                                                  
.
```

[image]

here is the [config.yml](http://52.29.40.51/config.yml) file

I changed the timezone on php.ini and i did a lot of research but without result . Can any one help me ? 
Thank You.

Comment: Can you share your parameters.yml file ?

Comment: foobar check the edits

Comment: I meant `parameters.yml`, not `config.yml`:(

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/ezsystems/ezplatform/blob/master/INSTALL.md and https://doc.ez.no/display/TECHDOC/Using+Composer ?

Comment: @foobar here is my parameters.yml  http://52.29.40.51/parameters.yml

Comment: Have you made any progress on this issue ? Your `parameters.yml` seems to be ok...